How to embed a Window from HDevEngine in my wxWidgets panel?
HDevEngine (Propietary software) is an interpreter for running Programs from a Skripting language in C++. This engine can also Run Pop-Up windows to show the results.
I want to avoid the HDevEngine to create a new window. Instead of that, I want to embed the window in an existing panel in my wxWidgets Frame.
I don´t now how  to start, just did this:
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "HalconCpp.h"
#include "HDevEngineCpp.h"
#include "HDevThread.h"
#include "my_error_output.h"
#include "my_hdevoperatorimpl.h"

using namespace HalconCpp;
using namespace HDevEngine;

// Definiere eine Klasse, die von wxFrame erbt
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title) 
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600))
    {
        // Erstelle ein horizontales BoxSizer
        wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

        // Erstelle zwei Panels und füge sie dem Sizer hinzu
        wxPanel* panel1 = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
        wxPanel* panel2 = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

        sizer->Add(panel1, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);
        sizer->Add(panel2, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

        // Setze den Sizer für das Frame
        this->SetSizer(sizer);

        HDevEngine my_engine;
        MyHDevOperatorImpl op_impl;
        my_engine.SetHDevOperatorImpl(&op_impl);
        std::string program_path = Data::get().getAppData().PathHdev;
        // Load program
        HDevProgram my_program;
        my_program.LoadProgram(program_path.c_str());

        // Erstelle ein HALCON-Fenster im ersten Panel
        Htuple windowID;
        OpenWindow(0, 0, panel1->GetSize().GetWidth(), panel1->GetSize().GetHeight(), (Hlong)panel1->GetHandle(), "visible", "", &windowID);
        HDevWindowStack::Push(windowID);

        // Führe das HDevelop-Programm aus
        hDevProgram.Execute();

        // Passe das Layout an
        this->Layout();
    }

    ~MyFrame() {
        // Schließe das HALCON-Fenster beim Zerstören des Frames
        if (HDevWindowStack::IsOpen())
        {
            CloseWindow(HDevWindowStack::Pop());
        }
    }
};

// Definiere eine Klasse, die von wxApp erbt
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        // Erstelle eine Instanz des Frames und zeige sie an
        MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Mein Fenster in wxWidgets mit zwei Panels");
        frame->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

// Implementiere das Hauptmakro
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);


look at the wxNativeWindow...

This behaviour may be only provided by wxNativeWindow class. Otherwise (likely, in your case) it is needed to interact with the windows owned by 3rd party application using a low-level native OS mechanism.
